# I'm having a problem with firebase when i deploy my project

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I made an application and finished it, and wanted to upload it to firebase. When I type in  the terminal "firebase deploy", everything appears fine, then the link to the site appears in the terminal normally.

But when I click on it to open the site, a message appears saying:

> **Firebase Hosting Setup Complete**
>
> You're seeing this because you've successfully setup Firebase Hosting. Now it's time to go build something extraordinary!

As you can see in the attached picture!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that index.html inside build folder and the one outside the build folder must be the same.
If they are same then try reloading after some time. When I was having the same issue it worked without doing anything and reloading after sometime (in my case around 10-15 minutes)

Here is a github issue that has detailed discussion on this.
https://github.com/coreui/coreui-react/issues/55