# Site Not Found Error After Deployed in Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, clone, suspend

This is my first project in firebase. I wanted to deploy in it. So that I had created Netflix Clone Web Application using TMDB API. I use VS Code as my code editor.

Initially I had struggle on opening my website in Google Chrome i.e., "IT SHOWED DANGEROUS SITE" but on proceeding with this page. It had shown the output.

After a day I got a e-mail from Google Cloud saying "my website has been suspended due to some non-compliance with their terms" then I request an appeal but my issue had not been solved.

Now, I am again opening my website and it shows this error:

> Site Not Found Why am I seeing this? There are a few potential
> reasons:
>
> You haven't deployed an app yet. You may have deployed an empty
> directory. This is a custom domain, but we haven't finished setting it
> up yet. How can I deploy my first app? Refer to our hosting
> documentation to get started.

If anyone know about this issue, kindly help me out or refer some websites regarding it.

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74990059/im-having-a-problem-with-firebase-when-i-deploy-my-project/74990264#74990264